# how to get all credit memo items in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.1

how to get all credit memo items in magneto 2

Answer (score 1):

You can include `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Collection` in your constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Collection $creditmemoCollection,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->creditmemoCollection = $creditmemoCollection;
    ...
}
```

And your function would be like this:

```
public function yourfunction() {
    ...
    $collection = $this->creditmemoCollection;

    foreach($collection as $creditmemo):
        ...
        $data = $creditmemo->getData();
        //If you want items, then use this:

        $items = $creditmemo->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach($items as $item){
            echo $item->getProductId();
            echo $item->getName();
        }
        ....
    endforeach;
}
```

You can also add filters with this: `$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gt' => $anyDate));`

Comment: i get an error Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Learning\HelloPage\Controller\Page\View\Interceptor

Comment: After adding the code above you need to run upgrade, di:compile commands. with out that your would get interceptor errors.

Comment: Sir this is work fine but i want credit memo item infroms from sales_creditmemo_item table.is it possible?

Comment: Answer updated, please check

Comment: sir data array is done.but inside loop array items not return anything

Comment: Check updated answer, check if you are getting item id in item loop

Comment: Actually i want product id and product name from sales_creditmemo_item table

Comment: That's item array, so yes you can get all the columns of that items in foreach loop. check updated answer

Comment: Main issue is items array not return anything

Comment: This should work. I guess you try this: `$collection = $this->creditmemoCollection->getItems();` to load first collection.

Comment: No sir $items = $creditmemo->getAllVisibleItems(); this statement nothing to return

Comment: sales_creditmemo_item have two rows but i did not get this